# Java dynamic proxy confusion

Tags: java

Is it possible to have an interface(A) extend another interface(B) and use the methods of the class that implemented the interface(B) ? Is this what dynamic proxy is all about?

Say we have

```
public interface A {
    String getMessage();
}

public class AImpl implements A{
    String msg = "Hello World";

    @Override
    String getMessage(){
        return this.msg;
    }
}

public interface B extends A {
}

public class main {

   B b;
   public main(B b){
      this.b = new B();
   } 

   System.out.println(b.getMessage()); // prints "Hello World"
}
```

Comment: This is polymorphism and interface inheritance, it has nothing to do with dynamic proxies.

Answer (score 1):

Dynamic proxy is about creating an object which implements some interfaces "dynamically" in the sense that it receives a `Method` object instead of just implementing these interfaces.

It's generally used when you either 1) determine which interfaces are used at runtime in some way; or 2) have very large interfaces where many methods can be implemented similarly.

This code has nothing to do with dynamic proxies. You *could* use a proxy to do what you ask about (but why would you want to?):

```
A a = new AImpl();
this.b = (B) Proxy.newProxyInstance(
    B.class.getClassLoader(),
    new Class<?>[] { B.class },
    new InvocationHandler {
        @Override
        Object invoke(Object proxy, Method method, Object[] args) throws Throwable {
            return method.invoke(a, args);
        }
    });
```